# Where is framework config for binding redirects?

Tags: .net, dll, .net-standard, assembly-binding-redirect

My `ASP.NET MVC` web backend consumes `System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll`. On build, the dll is found in:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.1\Facades`.

At runtime, the dll is resolved to:

`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll`.

This is what `fuslogvw` shows:

```sh
...
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: path\to\bin\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll
LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: A partially-specified assembly bind succeeded from the application directory. Need to re-apply policy.
LOG: Using application configuration file: path\to\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\xxx\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Version redirect found in framework config: 4.2.2.0 redirected to 4.0.0.0.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
```

I'm particularly interested in line
`LOG: Version redirect found in framework config: 4.2.2.0 redirected to 4.0.0.0.`

#### Question:

Where is that framework config mentioned above? None of the three files mentioned in the log (`web.config`, `machine.config`, `aspnet.config`) contain a binding redirect directive for `System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll`, so where is it then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line you are seeing is coming from the unification table that is inside the runtime.

The runtime has special knowledge of a handful of assemblies and for those is applies a special binding redirect *if* no user specified binding redirects are specified (in the locations you mentioned).

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know about that unification table.

Comment: Is this unification table explicitly documented somewhere, per framework version?